# Dynamically generate unique ID for DIV and CHECKBOX using razor

Tags: javascript, c#, html, razor, model-view-controller

This is my fist question, so please forgive me if it is poorly constructed.

I am learning `C#` `MVC 5` with `Entity-Framework 6`.

I'm trying to use `javascript` to show and check a `checkbox` and it's text which are encapsulated within a `div` so that I can hide/show the complete `checkbox` and value.

What I am struggling with however is creating a unique `ID="??"` for the `div` and the `checkbox` so that my javascript can access each portion of the DOM as needed.

Below is my View code:

```
@foreach (var item in ViewBag.allDocketTypes)
    {
        <div id="DockDIV @item.DocketTypeID" style="display:none" class="col-md-6">
            <input type="checkbox" class="input" id="DockCB @item.DocketTypeID" name="selectedDocketTypes" value="@item.DocketTypeID" />@item.DocketClassification
        </div>
    }
```

Next is my javascript function that I'm using to check the `checkbox` and change the `.style = "display:none"` for the `div` to `.style = "display:block"` for now:

```
function addDocketType() {
    var e = document.getElementById("DocketClassification");
    var strDocketTypeID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("DockCB " & strDocketTypeID).checked = true;
    document.getElementById("DockDIV " & strDocketTypeID).style = "display:block";
};
```

Right now I'm getting the below error when the javascript executes:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'checked' of null
```

Any ideas on how I should correctly set the `id` of these objects would be appreciated. Or I'd also take a better suggestion on how I can show and check a checkbox and it's value.

Comment: Are you sure that it is getting the correct `strDocketTypeID` here?  Also, consider using an underscore `_` in the ID and not a space.  The space could cause issues.  Finally, this code would become simpler if using `jQuery` which is fairly standard in MVC.  Have you considered it / are you able to use it?

Comment: I haven't considered `jQuery` for this. Any suggestions on how that would work?

Comment: The `_` seems to have sorted out. I also found that I needed to change the `&` to `+` and finally I needed to change the way I was setting the `.style` to `.style.display = "block"` Thanks for the help though @stephen.vakil

Answer (score 2):

I managed to resolve this one with help and pointers from @stephen.vakil +1 for you if I could :)

In short it's all about syntax...

In the View use an `_` when trying to use `razor` syntax inline to create a unique ID

```
 @foreach (var item in ViewBag.allDocketTypes)
    {
        if (item.TypeSelected)
            {
                <div id="DockDIV_@item.DocketTypeID" style="display: block" class="form-group-sm"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="DockCB_@item.DocketTypeID" name="selectedDocketTypes" value="@item.DocketTypeID" checked="checked"/>@item.DocketClassification</div>
            }
        else
            {
                <div id="DockDIV_@item.DocketTypeID" style="display: none" class="form-group-sm"><input type="checkbox" class="form-control" id="DockCB_@item.DocketTypeID" name="selectedDocketTypes" value="@item.DocketTypeID" title="TEST"/>@item.DocketClassification</div>
            }
    }
```

Concatenating strings in `javascript` is done with a `+`.

```
function addDocketType() {
    var e = document.getElementById("DocketClassification");
    var strDocketTypeID = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

    document.getElementById("DockCB_" + strDocketTypeID).checked = true
    document.getElementById("DockDIV_" + strDocketTypeID).style.display = "block"
};
```

and there we have it...